# Is the difference between in-place modification and not, some implementation details or something which programmers in Python need to know?

Tags: python

In *Python in a Nutshell*

> Assignment statements can be plain or augmented.
>
> Plain assignment to a variable
>   (e.g.,  name=value ) is how you create a new variable or rebind an existing variable to
>   a new value. Plain assignment to an object attribute (e.g.,  x.attr=value ) is a request
>   to object  x  to create or rebind attribute  'attr' . Plain assignment to an item in a
>   container (e.g.,  x[k]=value ) is a request to container  x  to create or rebind the item
>   with index or key  k .
>
> Augmented assignment (e.g.,  name+=value ) cannot, per se, create new references.
>   Augmented  assignment  can  rebind  a  variable,  ask  an  object  to  rebind  one  of  its
>   existing attributes or items, or request the target object to modify itself. When you
>   make a request to an object, it is up to the object to decide whether and how to
>   honor the request, and whether to raise an exception.
>
> ...
>
> In an augmented assignment, just as in a plain one, Python first evaluates the RHS
>   expression. Then, when the LHS refers to an object that has a special method for the
>   appropriate in-place version of the operator, Python calls the method with the RHS
>   value as its argument. It is up to the method to modify the LHS object appropriately
>   and return the modified object (“Special Methods” on page 123 covers special meth‐
>   ods).  When  the  LHS  object  has  no  appropriate  in-place  special  method,  Python
>   applies  the  corresponding  binary  operator  to  the  LHS  and  RHS  objects,  then
>   rebinds  the  target  reference  to  the  operator’s  result.  For  example,  x+=y   is  like
>   `x=x.__iadd__(y)`   when  x   has  special  method  `__iadd__`  for  in-place  addition.
>   Otherwise,  x+=y  is like  x=x+y .
>
> Augmented assignment never creates its target reference; the target must already be
>   bound  when  augmented  assignment  executes.  Augmented  assignment  can  rebind
>   the target reference to a new object, or modify the same object to which the target
>   reference was already bound. Plain assignment, in contrast, can create or rebind the
>   LHS target reference, but it never modifies the object, if any, to which the target ref‐
>   erence  was  previously  bound.  The  distinction  between  objects  and  references  to
>   objects  is  crucial  here.  For  example,  x=x+y   does  not  modify  the  object  to  which
>   name  x  was originally bound. Rather, it rebinds the name  x  to refer to a new object.
>   x+=y ,  in  contrast,  modifies  the  object  to  which  the  name  x   is  bound,  when  that
>   object has special method  `__iadd__` ; otherwise,  x+=y  rebinds the name  x  to a new
>   object, just like  x=x+y .

Is the difference whether an assigment performs **in-place modification** and **not-in-place assignment**, (e.g. used by augmented assignment and plain assignment), some implementation details  of Python, which programmers in Python don't have to know, or something belonging to the semantics which programmers need to know?  Note: in-place modification means change the value in a memory region, while not-in-place assignment allocates a new memory region.

If the answer is no, why do programmers in Python need to know the difference? Is there any situation where programmers in Python need to be aware of the difference?

I suspect that the difference is implementation details, and programmers in Python don't need to know the difference but only need to know the semantics of assignment.

Thanks.

Comment: It's an implementation detail of the *type* whose augmented assignment method is being used. Whether `x += 3` does any thing in-place depends on how `x.__iadd__` is implemented.

Comment: Augmented assignment was controversial back in the day because its not immediately apparent what happens to the assigned object. Consider `a = b;b += c`. What's in `a`? It depends on whether augmented assignment rebound a new object. if b and c are strings you get one thing, if b is a list you get another.

Comment: @chepner, the problem is that you may need to know what that implementation detail is. Suppose a function uses `+=` on an object passed in by the caller. Whether the caller's object was changed depends on how `__iadd__` was implemented.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. by implementation details, do you mean that whether an assignment perform in-place modification or not-in-place assignment is not  part of the semantics of the operation, and is not something a user/programmer needs to know?

Answer (score 3):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__) say, regarding the `__i<method>__` special methods:

> These methods are called to implement the augmented arithmetic assignments (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `@=`, `/=`, `//=`, `%=`, `**=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `^=`, `|=`). These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self). If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods. For instance, if `x` is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()` method, `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)` . Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`. In certain situations, augmented assignment can result in unexpected errors (see [Why does `a_tuple\[i\] += \[‘item’\]` raise an exception when the addition works?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-augmented-assignment-tuple-error)), but this behavior is in fact part of the data model.

To answer the question you pose:

> Is the difference between in-place modification and not, (e.g. used by augmented assignment and plain assignment), some implementation details of Python, which programmers in Python don't have to know?

Yes, you need to be aware of this when implementing data model for custom objects.

As a user of such objects, you would also better understand what you're doing when using augmented assignment if you understand this.

Why? If you don't implement in-place behavior, when performing augmented assignment, the name or lookup gets reassigned to a object that is the result of the standard implementation of the operation.

As an implementer, and as a user, you'll need to know this.

### follow-on question from asker:

> My question is about whether an assignment performs in-place modification and not-in-place assignment, not which method is invoked. in-place modification means change the value in a memory region, while not-in-place assignment creates a new memory region. I was wondering if such difference is implementation details which programmers don't need to know, or something belonging to the semantics which programmers need to know.

In Python everything is an object. Every object has a header with some details. Any object that contains other objects does not actually contain the object, rather it has a pointer, or reference, to the location in memory of the object it holds. Mutation of the object changes the reference to a new reference.

The old location of the old object only gets overwritten if the count of non-weak references to that object go to zero. You can think of this as an implementation detail, but knowledge of this helps one to be a more confident user of the language.

Users rarely need to be concerned with these details, but when you do, you'll be glad you understand it.

Again, your question:

> My question is about whether an assignment performs in-place modification and not-in-place assignment, not which method is invoked.

Which method is invoked determines the behavior. Therefore you need to know which method is being invoked - either from the semantics of the documentation of the objects you are using, or from your own knowledge of the Python data model - to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being unclear. My question is about whether an assigment performs in-place modification and not-in-place assignment, not which method is invoked.  in-place modification means change the value in a memory region, while not-in-place assignment creates a new memory region. I was wondering if such difference is implementation details which programmers don't need to know, or something belonging to the semantics which programmers need to know.

Comment: @Tim I have responded to your follow-on question

Answer (score 1):

*Is there any situation where programmers in Python need to be aware of the difference?*

Python is a dynamic language that gives you lots of polymorphism for free ([duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)). If a function is written to work on lists, it likely will work on many list-like things. Augmented assignment throws a wrench into that. Suppose a function adds data to a collection:

```
>>> def add_data(collection):
...     collection += ('tuple',)
... 
>>> l = []
>>> add_data(l)
>>> l
['tuple']
>>> t = tuple()
>>> add_data(t)
>>> t
()
```

It fails silently in the second case. This is a risk generally when you have multiple references to an object and an augmented assignment is applied to one of them. Its like a box of chocolates but in a bad way.